# Switch statement for RegExp falling to default?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

In this switch statement, why does it fail in the regex check and falls to the default case?

The regex matches when I do it as `if ... else`, but, it doesn't matches when I do it as a switch statement and it falls to the default case!

```js
let siteUrl = 'http://example.com';
let check1 = checkSite(siteUrl);
let check2 = checkSite();

function checkSite(siteUrl) {
    let url = (siteUrl) ? siteUrl : 'http://example.com';
    let regex = /^http:\/\/example\.com$/gi;
    let result = {};

    if (regex.test(url)) {
        console.log('regex match!');
    } else {
        console.log('regex does NOT match!');
    }
    
    switch (true) {
        case regex.test(url) : //<-- Why this fails?
            console.log('case 1'); 
            result.case = 1;
            break;
            
        case /another-regex/.test(url) :
            console.log('case 2');
            result.case = 2;
            break;
                        
        default : //<-- Why do I get here?
            console.log('default');
            result.case = 3;
    }
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alternatively use `match` instead and check if length is greater than 0. `test` seems to change even if you just log the value consecutively.

```js
function checkSite(siteUrl) {
  let url = (siteUrl) ? siteUrl : 'http://example.com';
  let regex = /^http:\/\/example\.com$/gi;
  let result = {};

  if (url.match(regex)) {
    console.log('regex match!');
  } else {
    console.log('regex does NOT match!');
  }

  switch (true) {
    case url.match(regex).length > 0 : //<-- this will match
      console.log('case 1'); 
      result.case = 1;
      break;

    case url.match(/another-regex/).length > 0 :
      console.log('case 2'); 
      result.case = 2;
      break;
          
    default : 
      console.log('default');
      result.case = 3;
  }
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

let siteUrl = 'http://example.com';
let check1 = checkSite(siteUrl);
let check2 = checkSite();
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess this happens because of what @Samathingamajig referred to in his answer ?

Comment: According to MDN, the [returned value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value) from `.match()` is: "An Array whose contents depend on the presence or absence of the global (g) flag, or null if no matches are found." --- Hence, your code can be changed to be `case url.match(regex) !== null :` instead, because, if no RegExp matches were found, we get a null, and we can't check the length of `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you remove your `if` check the code works as expected:

```js
let siteUrl = 'http://example.com';
let check1 = checkSite(siteUrl);
let check2 = checkSite();

function checkSite(siteUrl) {
    let url = (siteUrl) ? siteUrl : 'http://example.com';
    let regex = /^http:\/\/example\.com$/gi;
    let result = {};
    
    switch (true) {
        case regex.test(url) : //<-- Why this fails?
            console.log('case 1'); 
            result.case = 1;
            break;
            
        case /another-regex/.test(url) :
            console.log('case 2');
            result.case = 2;
            break;
                        
        default : //<-- Why do I get here?
            console.log('default');
            result.case = 3;
    }
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}
```

This is because when you store a RegExp to a variable, it stores state.

```js
let regex = /^http:\/\/example\.com$/gi;
const url = "http://example.com";

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(regex.test(url));
}
```

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

> JavaScript RegExp objects are stateful when they have the global or sticky flags set (e.g., /foo/g or /foo/y). They store a lastIndex from the previous match. Using this internally, test() can be used to iterate over multiple matches in a string of text (with capture groups).

> When a regex has the global flag set, test() will advance the lastIndex of the regex. (RegExp.prototype.exec() also advances the lastIndex property.)
>
> Further calls to test(str) will resume searching str starting from lastIndex. The lastIndex property will continue to increase each time test() returns true.
>
> Note: As long as test() returns true, lastIndex will not reset—even when testing a different string!
>
> When test() returns false, the calling regex's lastIndex property will reset to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
    switch (true) {
        case url.match(regex) :
            console.log('case 1'); 
            result.case = 1;
            break;
            
        case url.match(another-regex) :
            console.log('case 2');
            result.case = 2;
            break;
                        
        default :
            console.log('default');
            result.case = 3;
    }
```

Hope, it works!! XD